# How to add curved borders to react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, linear-gradients

How do I create a curved linear gradient design to my page in react native, any insight would be really appreciated.
I tried to require the image but quality gets distorted. Want to know if theres any way to create this using code itself

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxZ5J.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to create gradients you can use `react-native-linear-gradient` package in your project.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient

Now, for the image that you shared I tried creating it using the same package. Here, I've created 3 different gradients and placed them as children. You will need to tweak around the styling in order to get it to close to your UI design.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles?.mainContainer}>
      <LinearGradient
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
        colors={["#f4ac", "#ffafcc", "#00bbf9"]}
        style={styles.linearGradient1}
      >
        <LinearGradient
          start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
          end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
          colors={["#00bbf9", "#ffafcc", "#f4ac"]}
          style={styles.linearGradient2}
        >
          <LinearGradient
            start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
            colors={["#fff", "#fff", "#fff"]}
            style={styles.linearGradient3}
          ></LinearGradient>
        </LinearGradient>
      </LinearGradient>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#000",
  },
  linearGradient1: {
    height: 250,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
  },
  linearGradient2: {
    height: 200,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 200,
    borderTopRightRadius: 200,
    width: "100%",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignSelf: "center",
    transform: [{ scaleX: 1.5 }],
  },
  linearGradient3: {
    height: 170,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 200,
    borderTopRightRadius: 200,
    width: "83%",
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
  },
});
export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer! Works great